# How to load big ASCII rasters in Revolution R?

Tags: raster, r, import, esri-ascii-raster, big-data

Is there anyone in this site using Revolution R with big spatial data?

I am trying to load raster files (ascii format) into revolution R using the xdf format, with no luck. Did anyone tried this already?

Comment: If you have big rasters why are you storing them in this format? But, if you can install rgdal just load it with x = readGDAL("file.asc"), or for better memory handling the raster package with x = raster("file.asc"). It depends on what you need to do with them . . .

Comment: I will need to use the data as matrix. so i thought about importing directly in ascii format, but it's true it's huge. one option would be to use revolution r, but most of the examples are given for normal csv tables

Comment: Hmm, I was assuming you meant the "ESRI ASCII" grid format. Why Revolution R? Just memory issues? If these really are raster grids then that package in R is good, otherwise maybe the ff package for general out-of-memory data structures.

Comment: just memory issues, they have already installed some parallel packages that can help, however I am having some problems in adapting the file format(xdf) to gis data. I will see what I can find and will try to update the question with more info.

Comment: Have you tried `rxReadXdf` function? See Table 01 in [this](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/sites/default/files/big-data-wp.pdf) document.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the file extension of your ascii raster data (is it .asc?; or is it .xdf? because if it is the latter, then it is not ascii), and show a sample of it? Moreover, do you want to import your ascii raster in R, and convert it to .xdf format? If data is already in .xdf what do you mean with _" however I am having some problems in adapting the file format(xdf) to gis data"_? This sentence seems contradictory to what is written in the question. Please clarify, what type of file and data you have and what you want to do with it (and also where: R or Microsoft R?).